# Is there any visio like symbol set for Blender?

Tags: modeling, animation

I'm new to Blender and like it a lot. I'm looking for a symbol set kind of [Visio style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visio). Like network symbols (servers, disks, terminals) of database symbols (entitie, relations).

I would like to create a database architecture landscape in which you can fly around and visit the individual parts in the architecture.

**Q:** Is there any visio like symbol set for Blender?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Recoomed take the tour to learn about how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Visio at all and in fact it's the first time I hear about it, but a quick Google search reveals that it is possible to save diagrams created in it in SVG format. You can also import SVG format to Blender. If you press <kbd>F4</kbd> followed by <kbd>P</kbd> or go to Edit -> Preferences, navigate to the Add-ons tab and search for "SVG", you will find an option to enable SVG import add-on:

[image]

Other than that, Blender is a content creation software package, so you can also just make whatever diagrams using it's modelling and drawing tools. This is the way to go with most things, because you cannot expect to find assets for every single idea you imagine.